# position of (treble) clef in musixtex when I use \smallvalue or \tinyvalue

Tags: musixtex

The treble clef symbol moves to the right when I use `\smallvalue`. When I use `\tinyvalue` it moves to the right straight against the flat (or sharp) of the `\generalsignature`. Where could I move the clef to the left, the very beginning of the line for all music? I tried things like `\def\treble{kern-2pt\treble}`, but it helps nothing.
The distance from the left side beginning of the line is totally independent from `\elemskip` or `\noteskip`, it is the same in now more than 1.000 scores so the "mistake" has to be found in the deeper TeX definitions, and I am not really familiar with changing them.

For aesthetic reasons I would be pleased if somebody could tell me where the position of the clef is defined.

I set this in plain:

```
\input musixtex%1
\input musixcpt%2
\input musixlit% 3
\input musixext%4
\input musixlyr%5
\input musixec%6
\input pmx%7
\font\A=phvb8t at 9pt%
\hoffset=0mm% 
\hsize=80mm% 
\nopagenumbers% 
\instrumentnumber{1}% 
\setstaffs1{1}% 
\nobarnumbers% 
\generalsignature{-1}% 
\generalmeter{\allabreve}% 
\enableauxlyrics% 
\afterruleskip=0.4\afterruleskip% 
\setsize1\tinyvalue% or \smallvalue or no \setsize1 
\A\setlyrics{soprano}{Aan de oe-ver van het meer\rlap{,} luist'-ren ve-len naar de Heer\rlap{.}}% 
\forcelyrhyphenstrue% 
\parindent 0pt% 
\nostartrule% 
\startpiece% 
\accshift=0.5pt% 
\assignlyrics1{soprano}% 
\notes\qqsk\qu f\qu g\bsk\hsk\en\bar% 
\notes\qu h\ql j\ql k\ql j\hbsk\en\bar% 
\notes\qqsk\hu h\en% \zalaligne% 
\notes\ql j\qu h\hbsk\en\bar% 
\notes\ql j\qu h\qu g\qu h\hbsk\en\bar% 
\notes\hu f\caesura\en% 
\Endpiece% \end{music}%
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: rather more people would be able to answer your question if you provided a test file.

Comment: Thanks for adding some sample code. You seem to have created a second account. You can ask one of the moderators in chat to merge the two accounts for you so that your future edits don't need to be approved by other users.